# Why is MailMessage sent to any address from Windows Forms application, but not from ASP.NET application, when both are using the same SMTP-server?

Tags: .net, asp.net, smtp, winforms, smtpclient

I'm experiencing a mysterious (to me) error when sending e-mails through a SMTP-server from an ASP.NET web application. I get the famous error "unable to relay for xxx@yyy.zzz". What's mysterious to me is that when I cut and paste the exact same code that sends the e-mail into an usual .NET Windows Forms application, send the e-mail with this application, it all works just fine. This made me think that perhaps the problem is that the ASP.NET application runs as NETWORK SERVICE while the Windows Forms application runs on a domain user account, but it turns out that I have another ASP.NET application sending e-mail through the same SMTP-server running under NETWORK SERVER at the same IIS, and this application does not experience this problem.

I've further tried to send e-mails through the SMTP-server manually by telnet the SMTP-server on port 25 and running the SMTP-protocol manually, and it all works fine. The SMTP-server is not configured with any kind of authentication or SSL.

Another mysterious fact is that the ASP.NET application can send e-mails from an address within the same domain to an e-mail address within the same domain, but not to any address outside of the domain. But the Windows Forms application, that uses the exact same code, can send e-mails from any address to any address both within AND outside of the domain.

So to summarize:

- The ASP.NET application can send
  e-mails from addresses within the
  domain to addresses within the domain,
  but not to addresses outside of the
  domain.
- A Windows Forms application running
  the same code on the same computer
  can send e-mails from ANY address to
  ANY address.
- Another ASP.NET application on the
  same IIS running under the same
  account (NETWORK SERVICE) can send
  e-mails using the same SMTP-server
  from ANY address to ANY address.
- There is no authentication configured
  on the SMTP-Server.
- Both the ASP.NET application and the
  Windows Forms application utilizes
  the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient class
  to send a
  System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.

The code that sends the e-mail massage is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MailMessage mesasge = new MailMessage(txtFrom.Text, txtTo.Text, "Test mail", txtBody.Text);
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text)))  //Is false since txtUserName.Text is empty
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.Host = txtServer.Text;
            client.Port = 25;
            try
            {
                client.Send(mesasge);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtResponse.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

As far as I can understand, this should be a matter of configuration rather than coding issues. Do anyone have an idea what the problem might be, and perhaps how this could be solved? Thanx!

Comment: At the risk of sounding daft, what smtp server are you using?

Comment: Did you test with the same From address

Comment: Yes I did test using the same From adress. Unfortunately I dont know what SMTP-server are in use. I would bet on the one within IIS thoe....

Comment: You could see what version of SMTP it is by telneting into it.  From a dos window type in:telnet <smtpservername> 25
The first line that comes back in that window will normally identify the server, and tell you what version it is.

Comment: Correct. The SMTP server is ESMTP MailMarshal (v6.5.4.7535).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most definitely sounds like an authentication issue or, you are accidently using 2 different SMTP servers.

I recommend you enable logging in both applications, and view the log. When you view the log, you should be able to see the differences, and hopefully trace it back to your code.

To enalbe logging in System.Net.Mail, you need to add some entries to your .config file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />

    <sources>

      <source name="System.Net" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>

      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>

    </sources>


    <sharedListeners>
      <add
        name="MyTraceFile"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"                />
    </sharedListeners>

    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
 </configuration>
```

Here is a link with more info:

http://systemnetmail.com/faq/4.10.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. This was new to me and I'm sure I'll find use for it on many coming occasions. This worked wonderful on my dev machine, however, it did not work in my customers production environment. There were no log written to the filesystem. In production the application runs on a Windows Server 2003 machine on IIS 6. The application runs within an application pool as NETWORK SERCVICE, perhaps this has something to do with the log file not being written?

Comment: It's possible your log file ended up in your System32 directory.

Try had coding the path. So rather than using System.Net.trace.log, try: c:\System.Net.trace.log

If that doesn't work, manually create the file in notepad, and give the network service permissions to write to it.

Comment: Thanx for the advice. I checked in the System32 directory, but it's not there. I also c:\System.Net.trace.log, but no success. I also tried to manually create the file in notepad and give network service permissions to write to it, but still no success.

Comment: hmm...depending upon how busy your server is, you may want to use something like Filemon to see if/where your file is trying to be created. -- Dave

Answer (score 0):

Do you have impersonate = true in the web.config?

Doing this:

```
new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

As far as I know requires that the web.config be set to allow impersonate.

Try adding this to you web.config (if you dont have it there)

```
    <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"  />
```

Comment: I'm not specifying any credentials. The if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text))) is false so those lines are never hit. However, I did do the suggested entry in the web.config file. However, the problem remained. Thank you for the tip anyway!

Comment: Okay :( Well what normally happend on my side, if you do use that method to authenticate and you dont have the identity impersonate=true, then the Active directory ticket is invalid, and will give you things like invalid userid/password errors.  I have also often troubleshooted SMTP issues, with just telnet commands, but it does not sound like this will help you at all, because it works via the windows app.